# How to update the data browser channels in parse.com?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, parse-platform

I'm using [Parse.com](https://parse.com/) to send push notifications between devices through PFQuery as below

```
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setChannel:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"User%@",id];
[push setMessage:@"You have a new message"];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

It works fine. But, If I update the channels to any other object using,

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"Giants1" forKey:@"channels"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

The object got added to the channels in Data browser.

[image]

I just want to update the channels with the new object, not to add. How to do that? What is the PFquery to update channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
currentInstallation.channels = @[ @"Giants1" ];
```

to replace all existing channels. The method you are currently using is explicitly adding to the existing list.

You should also be able to use `setObject:forKey:` to replace the list.